# Error getting a single value from a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called notification and i am trying to get a single value  with findOne()

```
 var allnotices = Notifications.findOne({eventownernumber:"2"},{sort: {noticedate: -1, limit: 1}}).noticemessage;
```

I want to get the value where the `eventownernumber` is `2` and i want to get the latest record and i only want one record.

Even though `noticemessage` is part of the row fields,i get the error that `noticemessage` is undefined.

This is the schema

```
{
    "_id": "tmkWCydSKZtYdrKTZ",
    "eventoriginalid": "3bXvARk6K6yhee6Hi",
    "lat": "-1.851881824302658",
    "lng": "96.987469482421875",
    "eventownernumber": "1",
    "eventownernames": "Test 1",
    "eventtitle": "ci",
    "eventtime": "08:05",
    "invited": "0",
    "eventduration": "21",
    "eventtype": "notification",
    "eventcategory": "hackathon",
    "eventstatus": "11",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-11-02T12:38:40.378Z"
    },
    "noticedate": {
        "$date": "2016-11-02T16:50:53.394Z"
    },
    "noticenumber": "2",
    "noticenames": "Test 2",
    "noticemessage": "Test 2 has joined your event ci",
    "noticestatus": "12"
}
```

Why is `noticemessage` undefined?.

Comment: is that above json the result of your `console.log(allnotices);` ?

Comment: may be "eventownernumber": "1"  in the find collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four basic possibilities why `Collection.findOne(query).key` could yield an error:

1. There is no document matching the query therefore you're trying to reference `undefined.key`
2. The key in question doesn't exist in the returned document
3. The document exists in the database but isn't being published by the server *and* being subscribed to by the client
4. The document exists and is published and subscribed to but the subscription is not yet `.ready()`, i.e. you need to wait before you can access it.

A common defensive pattern is:

```
const oneDoc = myCollection.findOne(query);
let myVar = oneDoc && oneDoc.key;
if ( myVar ) {
  // do the thing
} else {
  // handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the number as integer for `eventownernnumber` (and please write it like `eventOwnerNumber`, which is a good practice for readability), not string. Either use `input type="number"` or convert the value to integer like this:

```
Number(valueHere);
```

The rest of your query looks fine to me but you don't need limit since you do `findOne()` and you find the newest inserted doc with `noticedate: -1`

Another thing is, you need to save the date like this in your `insert()`:

```
noticeDate: new Date() //your current query should give you the right document after this change
```

Comment: suggestion: also use msavin:mongol package if you don't. Its extremely useful